# Displaying custom help documentation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I am following these instructions to create and display custom help documentation: http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/matlab_prog/display-custom-documentation.html. I am making this help for a GUI I have written with GUIDE and was wondering if it was possible to go directly to the 'supplemental software' page, described in step 5, from my GUI. I plan to make this program into a standalone app. If there are other, better ways to create help documentation for a standalone app I would be happy to hear them too.

Answer (score 1):

It is not strictly necessary to embed the Custom help documentation in the MatLab documentation.

You can build your own documentation help by adding a dedicated `menu` in the `figure menu bar`.

Actually you can either costomize the standard `menu bar` by adding your personal items or define your own `menu bar` and add it to your `GUI` in place of the standard MatLab one.

Moreover you can also add `context menu` to any `uicontrol` in your `GUI` (`menu` that are activated by `right clicking` on the `uicontrol`).

Bot `menu` and `contextmenu` can get access to the documentation written in in several `format` (HTML, PDF, TXT, ...).

### Menu creation

You can create your own `menu` items either through `GUIDE` or `by code`

- On `GUIDE` you can select the `Menu Editor` tool on the `GUIDE` toolbar. It allows creating both `menu` and `context menu`.

[image]

By setting the `Mneu bar` property of the GUI window to `figure` your custon `menu` wil be `added` to the `figure menu bar`

By setting the `Mneu bar` property of the GUI window to `none` your custon `menu` wil be the only one displayed on the `figure menu bar`

- `by code` you create both `menu` and `context menu` by using, respectively, the `uimenu` and `uicontextmenu` built-in functions.

### Documentation visualization

Ones you've created your `menu` and / or `context menu` you can specify the document to be opened to each `menu item` in its `callback`:

- to open `HTML` documentation you can use the `web` function, it allows to open the documentation using either the default MatLab browser or a Custom browser

`web('my_doc.html') % Open doc with MatLab default browser, if the doc folder is not in the MatLab Path, add the full path`

`web('my_doc.html','-browser') % Open doc with custom browser, if the doc folder is not in the MatLab Path, add the full path`

- to open `PDF` documentation you can use the `open` function

`open('example.pdf')`

- to open `TXT` documentation you can use the `winopen` function

(`winopen('release_notes.txt')`

I've built a simple `GUI` to show the implementaion of `menu` and `context menu`: it consists of a `menu bar`, a `pushbutton` and an `axes`.

The `manu bar` contains only the item defined by the user (the `Menu bar` property bas been ste to `none`), nevertheless, an in item in the custon menu allows displaying also the standard MatLab menu bar

The `pushbutton` allows to plot in the `axes` the surface generated by the `peaks` function (just to have it doing somenting); more important, a `context menu` with two items has been added to the `pushbutton`. The user can access to the `pushbutton` documentation by `right clicking` on the `pushbutton`

Also I've wrote a standard MatLab `.m` script which create the same GUI with the same functionalities to show how to create `menu` and `context manu` by using `uimenu` and `uicontextmanu` functions.

In the following you can find both the source codes and a picture showing the GUI.

### GUIDE generated `.m` file

```
    function varargout = custom_menu_gui(varargin)
% CUSTOM_MENU_GUI MATLAB code for custom_menu_gui.fig
%      CUSTOM_MENU_GUI, by itself, creates a new CUSTOM_MENU_GUI or raises the existing
%      singleton*.
%
%      H = CUSTOM_MENU_GUI returns the handle to a new CUSTOM_MENU_GUI or the handle to
%      the existing singleton*.
%
%      CUSTOM_MENU_GUI('CALLBACK',hObject,eventData,handles,...) calls the local
%      function named CALLBACK in CUSTOM_MENU_GUI.M with the given input arguments.
%
%      CUSTOM_MENU_GUI('Property','Value',...) creates a new CUSTOM_MENU_GUI or raises the
%      existing singleton*.  Starting from the left, property value pairs are
%      applied to the GUI before custom_menu_gui_OpeningFcn gets called.  An
%      unrecognized property name or invalid value makes property application
%      stop.  All inputs are passed to custom_menu_gui_OpeningFcn via varargin.
%
%      *See GUI Options on GUIDE's Tools menu.  Choose "GUI allows only one
%      instance to run (singleton)".
%
% See also: GUIDE, GUIDATA, GUIHANDLES

% Edit the above text to modify the response to help custom_menu_gui

% Last Modified by GUIDE v2.5 19-Aug-2015 17:40:05

% Begin initialization code - DO NOT EDIT
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @custom_menu_gui_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @custom_menu_gui_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before custom_menu_gui is made visible.
function custom_menu_gui_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to custom_menu_gui (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for custom_menu_gui
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes custom_menu_gui wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = custom_menu_gui_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

% Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


%
% Callback for: 
%    Custom DOC -> Getting Started (HTML) -> Open with browser
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function open_with_browser_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open_with_browser (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

web('my_doc.html','-browser')

%
% Callback for: 
%    Custom DOC -> Getting Started (HTML) -> Open with MatLab browser
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function open_with_matlab_browser_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open_with_matlab_browser (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

web('my_doc.html')

%
% Callback for: 
%    Custom DOC -> Reference Manual (PDF)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function reference_manual_pdf_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to reference_manual_pdf (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
open('example.pdf')


%
% Callback for: 
%    Custom DOC -> Release Notes (TXT)
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function release_notes_txt_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to release_notes_txt (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

winopen('release_notes.txt')

%
% Callback for: 
%    Custom DOC -> Show Standard Menu
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function show_standard_menu_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to show_standard_menu (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

if(strcmp(get(gcf,'menubar'),'figure'))
   set(gcf,'menubar','none')
   set(hObject,'checked','off')
else
   set(gcf,'menubar','figure')
   set(hObject,'checked','on')
end

%
% Pushbutton callback, just to make it doing somenting
% 
% --- Executes on button press in plot_button.
function plot_button_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to plot_button (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
peaks


%
% Callback for pushbuton ContextMenu "Open Doc (HTML) 
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function open_plot_button_doc_html_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open_plot_button_doc_pdf (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

web('my_doc.html','-browser')

%
% Callback for pushbuton ContextMenu "Open Doc (PDF) 
%
% --------------------------------------------------------------------
function open_plot_button_doc_pdf_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
% hObject    handle to open_plot_button_doc_pdf (see GCBO)
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)

open('example.pdf')
```

### .m Script

```
% Create the Main Window
the_fig=figure('unit','normalized','menubar','none', ...
   'color',[0.9412    0.9412    0.9412],'position',[0.4    0.5    0.5    0.3]);
% Create the Axes
the_ax=axes('position',[0.07    0.1    0.5    0.7500],'unit','normalized');
% Create the Pushbutton uicontrol
the_pb=uicontrol('style','pushbutton','unit','normalized', ...
   'position',[.7 .7 .2 .2], 'string','Plot', ...
   'tooltipstring','Right Click for Menu','callback','peaks;');
% Create the Main Custom Menu
the_menu=uimenu(the_fig,'label','Custom DOC');
% Create the first sub-menu
the_sub_menu=uimenu(the_menu,'label','Getting Started (HTML)');
% Create the 2 menu items belongoing to the sub-menu
the_sub_menu_1=uimenu(the_sub_menu,'label','Open with browser', ...
   'callback',['web(''my_doc.html'',''-browser'')']);
the_sub_menu_2=uimenu(the_sub_menu,'label','Open with MatLab browser', ...
   'callback',['web(''my_doc.html'')']);
% Creater 3 su-menu belonging to the main menu
the_sub_menu_3=uimenu(the_menu,'label','Reference manual (PDF)', ...
   'callback',['open(''example.pdf'')']);
the_sub_menu_4=uimenu(the_menu,'label','Release notes (TXT)', ...
   'callback',['winopen(''release_notes.txt'')']);
the_sub_menu_5=uimenu(the_menu,'label','Show Standard Menu', ...
   'callback','show_std_menu');
% Create the uicontext menu of the pushbutton
the_context_menu=uicontextmenu;
% Create the menu items of the uicontext menu
uimenu(the_context_menu,'label','Open ODC (HTML)', ...
   'callback',['web(''my_doc.html'',''-browser'')'])
uimenu(the_context_menu,'label','Open ODC (PDF)', ...
   'callback',['open(''example.pdf'')'])
% Assign the uicontextmenu to the pushbutton
set(the_pb,'uicontextmenu',the_context_menu);
```

**show_std_menu.m script for `the_sub_menu_5 callback`**

```
% If the Figure menubar is on
if(strcmp(get(gcf,'menubar'),'figure'))
   % Remove it
   set(gcf,'menubar','none')
   % Un-check the menu item
   set(the_sub_menu_5,'checked','off')
% If the Figure menubar is off
else
   % Show it
   set(gcf,'menubar','figure')
   % Check the menu item
   set(the_sub_menu_5,'checked','on')
end
```

### The GUI

[image]

Hope this helps.