# Adding help to a deployed MATLAB application

Tags: matlab, matlab-deployment, matlab-compiler

I am creating a compiled MATLAB application with a GUI, created using GUIDE. I want a button in my application labelled 'Help' that opens a suitable document. I currently have this code behind my help button:

```
  % --- Executes on button press in helpButton.
function helpButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if exist('./my_prog_help.html/my_prog_help.html', 'file')
    !start trip_vierer_help.html\trip_viewer_help.html &
  elseif exist('./my_prog_help.txt', 'file')
    !start trip_viewer_help.txt &
  else
    warndlg('Help file not found.','Help Not Found','modal')
    uiwait();
  end
```

This works, but it opens and leaves open a Windows command window. Can I stop this extra window opening?

Alternatively, although this works, this must be an often encountered requirement. Has anyone else got a better solution?

The help doucment is many pages long.

I am using MATLAB r2014a with 64 bit Windows 7.

Comment: I've proposed [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662093/displaying-custom-help-documentation-in-matlab/32157072#32157072) some months ago; perhaps it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using :

`!start trip_viewer_help.html\trip_viewer_help.html &`

try using:

`[status,cmdout]=system('start trip_viewer_help.html\trip_viewer_help.html &');`

Comment: Although this opens a browser or editor as required, it also opens an un-necessary command window.

Answer (score 0):

@il_raffa has provided the answer in part of a very detailed reply to another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25662093/displaying-custom-help-documentation-in-matlab/32157072#32157072). Here is the relevant part to my detailed question. I could use:

```
% --- Executes on button press in helpButton.
function helpButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if exist('./my_prog_help.html/my_prog_help.html', 'file')
    web(trip_vierer_help.html\trip_viewer_help.html','-browser')
  elseif exist('./my_prog_help.txt', 'file')
    winopen('trip_viewer_help.txt')
  end
```

This will open the html in my default browser and the text in my default editor.

This will also work:

```
% --- Executes on button press in helpButton.
function helpButton_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
  if exist('./my_prog_help.html/my_prog_help.html', 'file')
    winopen(trip_vierer_help.html\trip_viewer_help.html')
  elseif exist('./my_prog_help.txt', 'file')
    winopen('trip_viewer_help.txt')
  end
```

Note, this is Windows specific.